# SharePoint IF OR AND statement

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

This is regarding on employee Status whether Active, Inactive or Archived.

Status is active when [Date End] column is blank or greater than TODAY.
status is Archived when [date end]'s YEAR is less than Today's YEAR(ex. 2012<2017) OR [date end]'s month is less than Today's month(ex. 03<04) AND [date end]'s year is less than Today's year(ex. 2012<2017)

below is my code

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Date End]),[Date End]>Today),"Active",(OR(VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"yyyy"))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"yyyy")),AND(VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"m"))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"m")),(VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"yyyy")))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"yyyy"))),"Archived","Inactive")))`

SharePoint is accepting my code but the value is either Active or #VALUE!
I don't understand and cant find the error. please help!

Comment: You can not use Today in a Calculated Column: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=today

Comment: As rightly said by @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. We can only use today if our item is going to get edited on daily basis. Else Today will only work once you add / edit the item.

Comment: @MonicaJagani, yep! im updating it everyday but TODAY column is not the issue here guys :)

Comment: what is actual logic of setting Archived status .... according to your requirement it should be less than current month (including year) ... is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your Formula,

Looks like you are missing an IF

`=IF(
    OR(
        ISBLANK([Date End])
        ,[Date End]>Today
    )
    ,"Active"
    ,(      <==== You missed an IF here?
        OR( 
            VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"yyyy"))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"yyyy"))
            ,AND(
                    VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"m"))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"m"))
                    ,(VALUE(TEXT([Date End],"yyyy")))<VALUE(TEXT(Today,"yyyy"))
                )
            ,"Archived"
            ,"Inactive"
        )
    )
)`